# Contest Solution: Al Gore Rhythm

Tags: python, python-3.x, programming-challenge, datetime

> **The Problem**
>
> After his brush with the Justice Department over fundraising with Buddhist monks, the Vice President devised a plan to
>   ensure that such activities are carried out in a more discrete manner and are kept less noticeable. Realizing the Democratic
>   National Committee’s need for more and more money in the campaign war chest, Mr. Gore devised a “rhythm method” for
>   accepting campaign donations from Buddhist monks and yet avoiding the conception of an independent counsel. Gore’s
>   theory is that if the donations are spaced no less than 28 days apart, an independent counsel will not be necessary.
>
> To help Mr. Gore keep track of when it’s okay to accept money from Buddhist monks, you must write a program to
>   automatically scan the White House email logs for messages from “veep@whitehouse.gov” addressed to“buddha@whitehouse.gov” (the code name for the Al Gore Rhythm Method). Each such email is a secret entry in Mr.Gore’s Buddhist monk fundraising dairy. Your program must send Mr. Gore (“veep@whitehouse.gov”) a reply to
>   each such email advising him when the next donation may be accepted. You should assume that the email was sent the day
>   that the donation was accepted. To maintain more secrecy, Mr. Gore refers to a Buddhist monk as a “BM.”
>
> **Sample Input**
>
> Your program must process the White House electronic mail log, stored in the file whmail.log as input. The mail log is
>   an ASCII text file which contains a sequence of one or more valid email messages. Each email message consists of a header
>   followed by the body. A header consists of exactly four lines, each of which begins with a unique keyword. The first line is
>   the sender line and begins with the keyword From which is followed by a character string representing the email address of
>   the sender. The second line is the recipient line and begins with the keyword To which is followed by a character string
>   representing the email address of the recipient of the message. The third line is the date line and begins with the keyword
>   `Date` which is followed by a character string representing the date on which the email message was received. The fourth
>   line is the subject line and begins with the keyword Subject which is followed by an arbitrary character string. A single
>   blank space separates the keyword on each header line from the character string that follows. The body of an email message
>   is simply a sequence of one or more lines of text any of which may be blank. The body begins on the fifth line of the email
>   message. There will be normal White House email interspersed with the Al Gore Rhythm email, but your program should
>   ignore all email other than those from “veep” to “buddha.”
>   Sample contents of `whmail.log` could appear as:
>
> ```
> From bill@whitehouse.gov
> To buffy@airhead.net
> Date Saturday, October 4, 1997
> Subject Get together
>
> Hey, honeypie. Ole Big Daddy sure is missin you. I’ll be a
> lookin for you to come around again this weekend.
> Love,
> Bill
>
> From veep@whitehouse.gov
> To buddha@whitehouse.gov
> Date Monday, October 6, 1997
> Subject BM
> Dear Buddha, I just had a BM. Please advise.
>
> From reno@justice.gov
> To bill@whitehouse.gov
> Date Wednesday, October 8, 1997
> Subject Roby Ridge
>
> Mr. President:
>   The situation with the lady in Roby is quickly deteriorating.
> I advise we use an Apache loaded with napalm to flush the crazy
> woman out. If it kills her, it serves her right for that Vaseline
> trick. Dead or alive, at least it will be over. If I don’t hear
> from you within the next hour, I’ll send for the chopper.
>
> Janet
> ```
>
> **Sample Output**
>
> The output of your program must be directed to the screen and must consist of a reply email for each Al Gore Rhythm email
>   found in the log. Each reply must specify the date on which the next donation may be accepted. Your output must be
>   formatted *exactly* as that below, which is the output corresponding to the sample input above.
>
> ```
> From buddha@whitehouse.gov
> To veep@whitehouse.gov
> Date Saturday, November 8, 1997
> Subject Re: BM
>
> Thank you for advising me of your BM. You may not have
> another BM until Monday, November 3, 1997.
> ```

**algore.py**

```python
import datetime

def search_match(t, f):
    return t.startswith('From veep@whitehouse.gov') and f.startswith('To buddha@whitehouse.gov')

def get_date(date):
    prefix = date.strftime('%A, %B ')
    day = date.strftime('%d').lstrip('0')
    postfix = date.strftime(', %Y')
    return '{0}{1}{2}'.format(prefix, day, postfix)

with open('whmail.log') as f:
    for line in f:
        if search_match(line, f.readline()):
            date, subject = datetime.datetime.strptime(f.readline().strip()[5:], "%A, %B %d, %Y"), f.readline()
            subject = 'Re:' + subject[7:]
            limit = date + datetime.timedelta(days=28)
            sent = limit + datetime.timedelta(days=5)
            print('From veep@whitehouse.gov\nTo buddha@whitehouse.gov\nDate {0}\nSubject {1}\nThank you for advising me of your BM. You may not have\nanother BM until {2}'.format(get_date(sent), subject, get_date(limit)))
```

Any advice on performance enhancement and solution simplification is appreciated, as are topical comments!

Comment: Could you specify exactly what version of Python and OS you are running? I'm not convinced that your code actually works correctly.

Comment: @200_success Python 3.7 on Windows 10. It runs perfectly for me; what kind of problem are you running into?

Comment: I just ran your program using Python 3.7.1 on Windows 10, and got no output, as I suspected. I would love to review this code, but cannot do so in good conscience.

Comment: @200_success Do you have the `whmail.log` file in the same directory?

Comment: Yes, of course. It would crash if it couldn't open the file.

Comment: @200_success Here's my output: https://i.imgur.com/S0NEV2O.png What's your suspicion as to why it doesn't output correctly for you?

Comment: I don't know what you do differently, but I don't get any output either (Python 3.5.2)

Comment: @Mast, et. al try adding an extra line to the top of the whmail.log file - after tinkering with the code and noting the order of `f.readline()` within the conditionals I realized that makes things dependent on order...

Comment: @T145 does the sample _whmail.log_ file have an odd number of new lines at the top?

Comment: I copied and pasted the text in the post verbatim to the file and no output appeared. The edits by 200 might have messed something up. I'll update the post w/ what I have.

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ The text in my latest edit should fix the problem.

Comment: Your latest edit shows an annoying, major bug in your code. You're not checking every line, you're checking every other line and it's following line. Which means things get screwed up if you expect lines on even numbers while they're on odd and vice versa. In effect, statistically, you'll only find half of the messages.

Comment: The problem is you're iterating with a `for line in f:` but `f.readline()` also increases the line count. That same count.

Comment: So I shouldn't follow the advice given [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/206599/contest-solution-hailstones), and instead use the `while` based format?

Comment: I have confirmed that this works with the example text in Rev1 and Rev3. I don't think this is off-topic, but it has a very serious bug. Which should be raised in a Code Review.

Comment: Now that there is a plausible explanation as to how the code might have appeared to work, I have retracted my close vote and posted an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Buggy / fragile code

As evidenced by the comments debating whether this code works or not, this code is fragile, if not outright broken.

- **In Python 2:** If you run the program in Python 2, it will crash and explicitly tell you what the problem is:

  ```
  $ python algore.py 
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "algore.py", line 14, in <module>
      if search_match(line, f.readline()):
  ValueError: Mixing iteration and read methods would lose data
  ```

  The problem is that you are using both `for line in f: …` and `f.readline()` to fetch text from `f`, and the two mechanisms don't interact well with each other:

  Imagine that you are implementing the code to support `for line in f: …`.  Rather than reading one character at a time from the buffer, you'd want to fetch a block of characters to fill a buffer, then scan that buffer for the line break.  But then, `f.readline()` also reads from `f` into a buffer, but *starting from where the first read left off*, which is likely beyond where the first line break is.

  One simple fix is to replace all calls to `f.readline()` with `next(f, '')`.  Then, you would be consistently treating `f` as a line-by-line iterator, and not mixing the two mechanisms.  But I'd still consider it to be poor style, since most people would assume that each iteration through the `for line in f: …` loop would consume just one line.
- **In Python 3:** In Python 3 appears to not suffer from that problem: `f.readline()` uses the same buffer as the line-by-line iterator for `f`.  However, your problem is that `if search_match(line, f.readline()):` **always consumes another line from the buffer**, whether or not `line` is a `From` header.  Therefore, if you put a `print(line)` immediately after `for line in f:`, you'll see that it's skipping some lines.

### Style

This simultaneous assignment of two variables is unnecessarily lengthening a line of code that is very long already.  It should be split up into two statements.

> ```
> date, subject = datetime.datetime.strptime(f.readline().strip()[5:], "%A, %B %d, %Y"), f.readline()
> ```

### Suggested solution

Since the challenge states that every message contains headers that occur in a predictable order, we can simply do pattern matching using a regular expression.  If `whmail.log` is not too large to fit entirely in memory, then the task would be greatly simplified by treating the file as one big string rather than a collection of lines.

The code to print the output would be more readable if you wrote the template as a triple-quoted multi-line string, with named placeholders instead of numbers.

Your `get_date()` function is poorly named, as "get" implies that you are retrieving a piece of data from some existing place.  It's actually a date-formatting function, though.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import re

BM_EMAIL_RE = re.compile(
    r'^From (?P<From>veep@whitehouse.gov)$\s+'
    r'^To (?P<To>buddha@whitehouse.gov)$\s+'
    r'^Date (?P<Date>.*)$\s+'
    r'^Subject (?P<Subject>.*)$\s+',
    re.MULTILINE
)

REPLY_TEMPLATE = """From buddha@whitehouse.gov
To veep@whitehouse.gov
Date {reply_date}
Subject Re: {subject}

Thank you for advising me of your BM. You may not have
another BM until {limit_date}."""

def format_date(date):
    # We want %e (day of month with no zero padding) instead of %d (day of
    # month with zero padding), but %e is not portable.  Perform substitution
    # as a workaround.
    return re.sub('0([0-9],)', r'\1', date.strftime('%A, %B %d, %Y'))

with open('whmail.log') as f:
    for email in BM_EMAIL_RE.finditer(f.read()):
        date = datetime.strptime(email.group('Date'), '%A, %B %d, %Y')
        print(REPLY_TEMPLATE.format(
            subject=email.group('Subject'),
            reply_date=format_date(date + timedelta(days=33)),
            limit_date=format_date(date + timedelta(days=28)),
        ))
```

Comment: What do you mean by "`%e is not portable`"?

Comment: The [`strftime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) documentation does not list `%e` as a directive. Rather, it says: "The full set of format codes supported varies across platforms, because Python calls the platform C library’s `strftime()` function, and platform variations are common. To see the full set of format codes supported on your platform, consult the _strftime(3)_ documentation." It happens that both GNU/Linux and Windows 10 produce a space-padded day of the month, but the documentation says we can't count on it to work everywhere.

Comment: Your solution doesn't seem to like quotation marks in the sample text. It breaks w/ an encoding error; is there a work-around?

Comment: Consult the documentation for [`open(…, encoding=…)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open).